# Group by id a dataset then create a new column subtracting different columns from current and subsequent row

Tags: r

I have found similar problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606360/r-subtract-value-from-previous-row-group-by), but not exactly the same. Here is my problem, I have the following data set:

```
> ds
  id      begin        end
1  1 2017-01-15 2017-01-17
2  1 2017-01-01 2017-01-03
3  2 2017-02-01 2017-02-28
4  4 2017-04-11 2017-05-11
5  3 2017-02-05 2017-02-10
6  4 2017-03-10 2017-03-20
7  1 2017-01-30 2017-02-03
8  3 2017-02-28 2017-03-09
9  4 2017-02-26 2017-03-05
```

I want to create the following column: `check` that verifies the following condition for each rows with the same `id` value:

```
ds[i,]$begin - ds[i-1,]$end < 30 => 1 # for each row i
```

otherwise is `0`. When it is the first element of the group, then there is no previous information, so in such case the value of the new column `check` will be always zero too.

The difference with other questions (solved via: `ave`, `dplyr`) I have seen, is that I need to make a calculation that involves subsequent row but also not the same column.

Here is the code:

Defining the data set

```
id <- c("1", "1", "2", "4", "3", "4", "1", "3")
begin <- c("20170115", "20170101", "20170201",
    "20170411",
    "20170205", "20170310",
    "20170130", "20170228"
    )

end <- c("20170117", "20170103", "20170228",
    "20170511",
    "20170210", "20170320",
    "20170203", "20170309"
    )

ds <- data.frame(id = id, begin = as.Date(begin, "%Y%m%d"), end = as.Date(end, "%Y%m%d"))
```

Sorting the information (we need it for the current solution using a for-loop)

```
idx = order(rank(ds$id), ds$begin, decreasing = FALSE)
ds <- ds[idx,]
```

Now using the for-loop for assigning the control variable: `check`:

```
ds$check <- numeric(nrow(ds))
ds$check <- NA_integer_

nrep <- -1
for (i in 1:nrow(ds)) {
    rowi <- ds[i,]
    if (nrep == -1) {# Setting the first element of ds
        end.prev <- rowi$end
        id.prev <- rowi$id
        ds[i,]$check <- 0
        nrep = 1
    } else {
        id.current <- rowi$id
        if(id.prev == id.current) {
            ds[i,]$check <- ifelse(rowi$begin - end.prev < 30, 1, 0)
        } else {
             ds[i,]$check <- 0
        }
        end.prev <- rowi$end
        id.prev <- id.current
    }
}
```

Finally the expected output:

```
> ds
  id      begin        end check
2  1 2017-01-01 2017-01-03     0
1  1 2017-01-15 2017-01-17     1
7  1 2017-01-30 2017-02-03     1
3  2 2017-02-01 2017-02-28     0
5  3 2017-02-05 2017-02-10     0
8  3 2017-02-28 2017-03-09     1
6  4 2017-03-10 2017-03-20     0
4  4 2017-04-11 2017-05-11     1
>
```

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Yes, it works! I don't know even how. Please can you explain a little bit how it works, there no so much documentation about `dplyr`, at least I found always very basic examples. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, see my answer for explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`, using `lag` makes this easy:

```
ds %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(id, begin) %>% 
  mutate(check = c(0, as.numeric(begin - lag(end) < 30)[-1]))
```

Gives:

> ```
> Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
> Groups: id [4]
>
>       id      begin        end check
>   <fctr>     <date>     <date> <dbl>
> 1      1 2017-01-01 2017-01-03     0
> 2      1 2017-01-15 2017-01-17     1
> 3      1 2017-01-30 2017-02-03     1
> 4      2 2017-02-01 2017-02-28     0
> 5      3 2017-02-05 2017-02-10     0
> 6      3 2017-02-28 2017-03-09     1
> 7      4 2017-03-10 2017-03-20     0
> 8      4 2017-04-11 2017-05-11     1
> ```

Explanation:

- First we `group_by`, so calculations are done by `id`.
- We `arrange` to make sure we start with the earliest date.
- For all `check`s, the first value is `0`,
- and the other values are simply whether the current `begin` minus the previous `end` is smaller than 30. We use `as.numeric` to convert from logical to numeric.

Also see: `vignette('window-functions')`.

Note: I think the first value per group can simply be left at `NA`, since it is indeed unknown or undefined, and this will simplify it to:

```
ds %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(check = as.numeric(begin - lag(end, order_by = begin) < 30))
```

Comment: In my real case I need to put a zero in the first row of the group. I understand for this second approach (with `NA`) in order to have the solution sorted we need to add: `arrange(id, begin) %>%`. What do you mean in your solution by: `[-1]` in this context? Good tip for vignette documentation. Can you share more reference documentation about this topic. It is still for me difficult to understand the syntax. Thanks.

Comment: The code `[-1]` excludes the first element of the vector, so we can have 0 instead. That is all the docs there is, as far as I know.

Comment: I found this web [page](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) with several resources about `dplyr`package. Here is the [data camp](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/dplyr-data-manipulation-r-tutorial) training. I shared an equivalent one information for `data.table` (comment on @ShenglinChen answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use data.table:

```
setDT(ds)[,New:=as.numeric(begin-shift(end,fill=0)<30),id]
```

Use dplyr:

```
ds%>%group_by(id)%>%mutate(new=as.numeric(begin-lag(end,default=0)<30))%>%arrange(id)
```

Comment: You are assuming the dates are sorted, but they are not. Good call on the use of `default` though.

Comment: @ShenglinChen very nice solution with `setDT` and `data.table`, and by the way this package has a very nice [tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-table-data-manipulation-r-tutorial). In both cases the result is not the expected. See for example the result for: `[1, "200170101", "20170103"]` you get `1` and it should be `0`. We need to specify a grouping first (by `id` then by `begin` in ascending order) otherwise it gets a wrong result I guess.

Comment: @ShenglinChen I edited your solution adding the arrange clause, now it get the expected result. Once I will figure it out how to apply the same for `data.table`, and I will edit again the solution.

Comment: @ShenglinChen, the edit was rejected, here is the change in order to get the expected result: `ds %>% group_by(id) %>% 
       arrange(id, begin) %>% 
       mutate(new = as.numeric(begin - lag(end, default = 0) < 30))`