# R - geom_bar - 'stack' position without summing the values

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have this **data frame**

```
df <- data.frame(profile = rep(c(1,2), times = 1, each = 3), depth = c(100, 200, 300), value = 1:3)
```

This is my **plot**

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = df, aes(x = profile, y = - depth, fill = value), stat = "identity")
```

My **problem** is the y labels which doesn't correspond to the depth values of the data frame

To help, my desired plot seems like this :

`ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = profile, y = depth, colour = value), size = 20) + 
  xlim(c(0,3))`

But with bar intead of points vertically aligned

**nb :** I don't want to correct it manually in changing ticks with `scale_y_discrete(labels = (desired_labels))`

Thanks for help

Comment: Why are you using `max` in y-axis?

Comment: Correct ! It is not necessary. I have edited the post

Comment: What's your expected output bar?

Comment: My expected output bar is a bar with ticks from 0 to -300

Comment: How's that possible, when you group you data with profile, 1 will have value 600? that brings to the question what you want in your x-axis?

Comment: I edited my post in adding a plot which is similar to my wished plot

Comment: `ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(profile), y = -depth, fill = value, group = interaction(profile, value))) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')`?

Comment: It's the way I  wish. The last step is to stack the columns without summing up the depth

Comment: You can overplot, but it is tricky to set the `group` correctly (in order to plot the smallest bar on top). `ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(profile), y = -depth, fill = value, group = factor(interaction(profile, value), rev(interaction(profile, value))))) + 
  geom_col()`. Note that this plot is ambiguous as to what the bars mean (true values or sums).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it !

Thanks for your replies and to this post [R, subtract value from previous row, group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606360/r-subtract-value-from-previous-row-group-by)

To resume; **the data :**

```
df <- data.frame(profile = rep(c(1,2), times = 1, each = 3), depth = c(100, 200, 300), value = 1:3)
```

Then we **compute the** **depth step of each profile** :

```
df$diff <- ave(df$depth, df$profile, FUN=function(z) c(z[1], diff(z)))
```

And finally the **plot** :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(profile), y = -diff, fill = value)) + geom_col()
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want a y-axis from 0 to -300, using `facet_grid()` seems to be a right option without summarising the data together.

`ggplot() + geom_bar(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(profile), y = -depth, fill = value), stat = 'identity') + facet_grid(~ value)`

[image]

Comment: To help, my desired plot seems like this :

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = profile, y = depth, colour = value), size = 20) + 
  xlim(c(0,3))

But with bar intead of points vertically aligned

Comment: But remember then it'll have value upto 600 because of the total sum. You can one like this or side by side bars.