# Substract date from previous row by group (using R)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lag

I'm having a similar question to this one ([subtract value from previous row by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606360/subtract-value-from-previous-row-by-group?answertab=active#tab-top)), but I want to subtract the previous date from the current date, by group ID in order to have an estimated number of days. I tried editing the scripts suggesed previously by replacing "value" by 
"date". 
Although I tried different suggested methods, but i keep getting this error message "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: unable to find an inherited method for function first for signature "POSIXct"."

```
Data
id      date        
2380    10/30/12    
2380    10/31/12    
2380    11/1/12     
2380    11/2/12     
20100   10/30/12    
20100   10/31/12   
20100   11/1/12     
20100   11/2/12     
20103   10/30/12
```

I'd like to get this kind of table

```
Data
id      date        date_difference(in days)
2380    10/30/12    0
2380    10/31/12    1
2380    11/1/12     2
2380    11/2/12     3
20100   10/30/12    0
20100   10/31/12    2
20100   11/1/12     3
20100   11/2/12     4
20103   10/30/12    0
20103   10/31/12    1
```

Comment: `?as.Date`, `?diff`, `c(0, diff( ... ))`

Comment: for the grouping part also look at: `data.table::`, `dplyr::` or `?base::ave`.

Comment: also: `20100   10/30/12    1` should be `20100   10/30/12    0`, right?

Comment: If you really mean *"subtract the previous date from the current date"*, then most of your `date_difference` values are incorrect. Perhaps you mean *"subtract the date from the first date by `id`"*?

Comment: See also `?dplyr::lag`

Answer (score 4):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

df <- tribble(~id,      ~date,      
2380,    "10/30/12",    
2380,   "10/31/12",    
2380,  "11/1/12",  
2380,    "11/2/12",  
20100,   "10/30/12",    
20100,   "10/31/12",   
20100,   "11/1/12",   
20100,   "11/2/12",   
20103,   "10/30/12",
20103,   "10/31/12")

df %>% 
  mutate(date = mdy(date)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(date_difference = as.numeric(date - first(date)))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>       id date       date_difference
#>    <dbl> <date>               <dbl>
#>  1  2380 2012-10-30               0
#>  2  2380 2012-10-31               1
#>  3  2380 2012-11-01               2
#>  4  2380 2012-11-02               3
#>  5 20100 2012-10-30               0
#>  6 20100 2012-10-31               1
#>  7 20100 2012-11-01               2
#>  8 20100 2012-11-02               3
#>  9 20103 2012-10-30               0
#> 10 20103 2012-10-31               1
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks. it is much more easier compared to the stringi derived scripts

Answer (score 0):

First, create a function to compute the day differences

```
library(stringr)

day_diff <- function(day) {
    days <- difftime(day, "2012-10-30", "days")
    str_extract(days, "\\-*\\d+\\.*\\d*")
}
```

Then create a new column containing the day differences

```
df$date_difference <- unlist(lapply(df$date, day_diff))
```

You may see warnings() of the lack of time zones, but you can signify (or ignore) there.