# Days difference between two dates in same column in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe with an ID and date column. I wish to calculate the days difference between the date1 and next date for a group.

I have already tried with dplyr package , it seems wrong.

```
hist_trnx1 %>% group_by(card_id) %>% mutate(gap=round(c(NA,diff(purchase_date)), 1))
```

I would like to get the results as below

```
   Card_ID         date                  Diff   
1. C_ID_4e6213e9bc 2017-06-25 15:33:07   NA
2: C_ID_4e6213e9bc 2017-07-15 12:10:45   20
3: C_ID_4e6213e9bc 2017-08-09 22:04:29   34 
4: C_ID_4e6213e9bB 2017-03-10 10:06:26   NA #( Because of group change) 
5: C_ID_4e6213e9bB 2017-04-10 01:14:19   30 
6: C_ID_4e6213e9bD 2018-02-24 08:45:05   NA #( Because of group change )
7: C_ID_4e6213e9bD 2018-03-23 08:45:05   29
```

**data**

```
structure(list(card_id = c("C_ID_4e6213e9bc", "C_ID_4e6213e9bc", 
"C_ID_4e6213e9bc", "C_ID_4e6213e9bc", "C_ID_4e6213e9bc", "C_ID_4e6213e9bc"
), purchase_date = structure(c(1498404787, 1500120645, 1502316269, 
1504346786, 1489108459, 1519461905), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), .Names = c("card_id", "purchase_date"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: What is the expected output.  Here, I don't see any difference in the 'Card_ID' in your dput

Comment: My bad  .. Here is the correct one

Comment: structure(list(card_id = c("C_ID_4e6213e9bc", "C_ID_4e6213e9bc", 
"C_ID_4e6213e9bB", "C_ID_4e6213e9B", "C_ID_4e6213e9bD", "C_ID_4e6213e9bD"
), purchase_date = structure(c(1498404787, 1500120645, 1502316269, 
1504346786, 1489108459, 1519461905), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), .Names = c("card_id", "purchase_date"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103000778>)

Comment: Please update your question with the correct data needed to make your problem reproducible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the prettiest way to go, and someone will probably offer a cleaner solution, but this should work (part of the solution found at : [subtract value from previous row by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606360/subtract-value-from-previous-row-by-group) )

First of all, I import your data :

```
df <- structure(list(card_id = c("C_ID_4e6213e9bc", "C_ID_4e6213e9bc", "C_ID_4e6213e9bB", "C_ID_4e6213e9B", 
                                  "C_ID_4e6213e9bD", "C_ID_4e6213e9bD" ), 
                      purchase_date = structure(c(1498404787, 1500120645, 1502316269, 1504346786, 1489108459, 1519461905), 
                                                tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), 
                 .Names = c("card_id", "purchase_date"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

And then it works when I run :

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(card_id) %>%
  arrange(purchase_date) %>%
  mutate(diff = purchase_date - lag(purchase_date, default = first(purchase_date))) %>%
  mutate(diff = round(diff/86400, digits = 2))
```

The *arrange* allows you to be sure you're substracting what you want to substract, then the *lag* function allows you to choose the previous row, and finally the division returns the number of days spent.

I hope that helps you =)