# Time elapsed in R

Tags: r

I have a large database (some data shown as example)

| Check_In | Ward_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:05:18 | 2019-01-01 00:09:32 |
| 2019-01-04 23:53:21 | 2019-01-05 08:09:36 |
| 2019-01-07 00:15:40 | 2019-01-07 10:43:53 |

I want to calculate the elapsed time from Check_In to Ward_1 for each row to get so

| Check_In | Ward_1 | Time_Elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:05:18 | 2019-01-01 00:09:32 | 00:04:14 |
| 2019-01-04 23:53:21 | 2019-01-05 08:09:36 | 08:16:15 |
| 2019-01-07 00:15:40 | 2019-01-07 10:43:53 | 10:28:13 |

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033585/calculating-time-difference-between-two-columns ?

Comment: You can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67063020/calculate-time-difference-in-the-same-group/67063168

Answer (score 0):

You can use `difftime` :

```
df1$Time_Elapsed <- difftime(df1$Ward_1, df1$Check_In, units = 'mins')
```

If you want output in hours, minutes and second format you can use `seconds_to_period` from `lubridate`.

```
df1$Time_Elapsed <- lubridate::seconds_to_period(difftime(df1$Ward_1, df1$Check_In, units = 'secs'))
```