# data set usage and variable selection

Tags: r

I uploaded the dataset.
but how do I show those who died in Europe.

`df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19-timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv')`

`europe <-- df[df$region =="Europe"]`

`df$death [europe]`

Comment: Do you need `df[df$region =="Europe", ]` ?

Comment: He says that the object "europe" could not be found. this is what I want to learn. To find the death numbers of the European countries only in the dataset.
to show the country name and number of deaths in two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can also use the `subset` in `aggregate`

```
aggregate(death~countryName, df, subset = region =="Europe"), sum)
```

---

Or using `rowsum`

```
with(subset(df, region == 'Europe'), rowsum(death, countryName))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can filter only the European countries and calculate number of deaths by country.

This can be done in base R :

```
df1 <- aggregate(death~countryName, subset(df, region =="Europe"), sum)
```

`dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
        filter(region == 'Europe') %>% 
        group_by(countryName) %>% 
        summarise(total_death = sum(death))
```

and in `data.table`

```
df1 <- setDT(df)[region == 'Europe', (total_death = sum(death)), countryName]
```

Comment: thank you so much. I want to ask one more thing . I have to subtract from the previous day to find the number of new patients. how to select the previous day in the dataset. with what code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Probably you should ask that as a new question but I think this post might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606360/subtract-value-from-previous-row-by-group

Comment: I will ask. but I want to learn something. In the data set, the number of deaths is given for each day. the code you have created has collected every day. my wish is only deaths. The prefix is ​​enough to give the number of deaths of the day. He added the numbers of deaths everyday to date and added them. high figures.

Comment: I see. Probably you need `max` then. `df1 <- aggregate(death~countryName, subset(df, region =="Europe"), max)`

Comment: not max. because he doesn't want the highest death. he wants to know how many died yesterday.