# Calculate difference between values in rows by two grouping variables

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I want to use the ave solution from this question: [subtract value from previous row by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606360/subtract-value-from-previous-row-by-group) with two groups.

```
#Reproduceable example db:
FU <- c(5,10,20,2,7,20,6,14,8,20,15,17)
Studynr <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6)
Fugroup <- c(1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,2,0,1,0)
db <- data.frame(Studynr,Fugroup,FU) 

# code to calculate the difference consequetively
db$FUdiff <- ave(db$FU, db$Studynr, FUN=function(x) c(NA,diff(x)))
```

This is the head of the table this code provides:

| FU | Studynr | Fugroup | FUdiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 10 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 20 | 2 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | -18 |
| 7 | 3 | 0 | NA |
| 20 | 3 | 1 | 13 |

But what I want is (switching 5 and NA, because FU group is ordered as 1 to 0)

| FU | Studynr | Fugroup | FUdiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | **5** |
| 10 | 1 | 0 | NA |
| 20 | 2 | 0 | NA |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | -18 |
| 7 | 3 | 0 | NA |
| 20 | 3 | 1 | 13 |

I think the ave code is not working for me as the data per group isn't consecutively sorted in the database. Therefore, instead of using one grouping variable (db$Studynr), I would like to use a second grouping variable (db$Fugroup). Any ideas? Thanks!

(adjusted post)

Comment: Please `dput` your example data and show your desired result.

Comment: "Unfortunately this code is not working for me as the data per group isn't consecutively sorted in the database." What's your real inconsecutive data here?

Comment: How do you get diff as 0.61 and 1.64 ? What is the calculation?

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing, I want to difference to be calculated consecutively so: The first date (15:32) has value 23.11, the second (15:51) 21.01, so that 2.10 difference. The third date (16:02) has 22.65, so that's 1.64 difference from the second date. The difference in my own data is that I have a categorical variable (instead of time as in the example). I am currently making better example data!

Comment: Just changed the post, so it only shows example data (instead of the data from a previous post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `order` the data first and apply the `ave` code :

```
db <- db[with(db, order(Studynr, Fugroup)), ]
db$FUdiff <- ave(db$FU, db$Studynr, FUN=function(x) c(NA,diff(x)))
```

You can implement the same logic in `dplyr` and `data.table` :

```
#dplyr
library(dplyr)

db %>%
  arrange(Studynr, Fugroup) %>%
  group_by(Studynr) %>%
  mutate(FUdiff = c(NA, diff(FU))) %>%
  ungroup -> db

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(db)[order(Studynr, Fugroup), FUdiff := c(NA, diff(FU)), Studynr]
```